# KVM (libvirt) in private mode with ipv6

Tags: kvm, libvirt

I have a server that has 5 NICs. I want to use 3 of them for my virtual machines. So I set up something like this as my default network in my debian host:

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <forward mode='private'>
    <interface dev='eno2'/>
    <interface dev='eno3'/>
    <interface dev='eno4'/>
  </forward>
</network>
```

I set it to private because I do not need my guests to communicate and they mostly each just run one service (mail/webserver, CTF test vm, A compute server with sage jupyter...).
I get assigned correctly ipv4 addresses from my router and ipv6 subnets. But only ipv4 works.
For some reason the host gets assigned ipv6 addresses on the interface too (not sure if this is supposed to happen). But nothing is reachable over ipv6.
On the guest all addresses are marked as noprefixroute.

Eg it looks something like this:
Guest:

```
─$ ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ff:23:00:ff:23:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.7.86/24 brd 10.0.7.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 86236sec preferred_lft 86236sec
    inet6 2a02:5:0:0:0:0:0:1/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 604637sec preferred_lft 85668sec
    inet6 2a02:5:0:0:0:2:0:1/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::beef:beef:beef:bded/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Host:

```
 ip a s
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
(..)
10: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ff:fe:cc:dd:bb:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0f0
    inet6 2a02:5:0:0:1:2:3:4/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::beef:beef:beef:57e3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: macvtap2@eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 500
    link/ether 52:54:00:87:e7:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::acab:acab:acab:beef/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

(I changed the IP's in the examples because of privacy, but you get the idea.)

Now if I leave out the networking of libvirt altogether and directly attach the NIC by using  with the relevant pci id's, then all works fine: however in that case I am limited to using only 1 vm because two ports always form an (IOMMU group) and I want to use the first port for the host and another one for the configuration interface. Also the performance seems to suffer in this case. So this is not an ideal solution.

Ideally what I want is for each VM to behave just as if I connected it physically by a cable to my switch. Each should get a publicly routable ipv6 network and address assigned (and ipv4 by nat from the router).
At the moment all ports are connected to the same switch and the switch is doing isolation to make sure each connected device can only talk to the internet and each port gets assigned a different ip4 and ip6 subnet.

I am a bit confused why this is such a confusing task. If I just connect 3 physical severs to the switch in the same way all works as expected.

I also tried the config example with the bridge networking, but it does not work either and I prefer not to set any ip's in my config as they could change and the router takes better care of assigning them correctly (with dhcpv6 I guess).